# Rails, Add other's records value to the another record values at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to add one record's value to the another record's value at the end as key and value.

```
@data = UserPost.
  includes(:user_likes, :comments).
  where('user_likes.flag = ?', false).
  where("#{@data1.values.join(' ')}").
  order('user_likes.created_at DESC').
  references(:user_likes :comments, :m_user_detail).
  paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
```

output of above query

```
# id: 1,
# user_id: "001",
# user_o_id: nil,
# message: "complete！",
# o_id: nil,
# o_name: nil,
# image_name: "image.jpeg",
# image_content_type: "image/jpeg"
```

add data of below query to above query at the end last_name and first_name

```
@data2 = UserDetail.select('user_id, last_name, first_name').where("user_id IN (?)", @userlist)
# user_id: "001", last_name: "shinde", first_name: "rohit"
# user_id: "037534", last_name: "mane", first_name: "pravin"
```

Comment: What about your code is not working?

Comment: I want to add `last_name: "shinde", first_name: "rohit"` at end of 1st query records

Answer (score 1):

Does including `user` & `user_details` in your query help? Checkout the code below

```
@data = UserPost.
  includes(:user_likes, :comments, user: [:user_details]).
  where('user_likes.flag = ?', false).
  where("#{@data1.values.join(' ')}").
  order('user_likes.created_at DESC').
  references(:user_likes :comments, :m_user_detail).
  paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
```

Now you should be able to access user's name from user_details table

```
@data.first.user.user_details.last_name # shinde
```